# Sorting Tree Node and tacking nodes

Tags: java

1) I have a tree and I will be inserting nodes into it during run time, may I know how to keep them sorted in natural order because the node will be after the last index.

Example: user add a product belonging to electronics, the product will appear under electronic category on everyone else "view". May How i know how to ensure the nodes under "electronics" will be sorted in natural order?

2) In my tree there are some objects that appear in another branch, May I know how to track those type of nodes?(2 different node but with the same data)

Yes I use hashmap to track normal nodes but I have problem find a solution for this issue.

The purpose of tracking is to update the nodes when there is an edit or update or insert into child...

I am thinking of using a object as the key or the hashmap so each object be individually identified.

Comment: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/15/sort-jtree/ -> Solution to problem one

Answer (score 1):

1) Basically, you're going to have to figure this out your self.

Assuming you know the parent, you could ask the parent node to pass back an index of where the new node would be inserted.  You could then use this information when calling `defaultTreeMode.insertNodeInto(MutableTreeNode child, MutableTreeNode parent, int index)` method.

Look up `Comparable` and `Comparator` for some ideas on this

2) How do mean by track?

Comment: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/15/sort-jtree/ -> I guess is the same solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Which type of data structure you are inserting in nodes. If you insert any class you can use an extra variable like position where you can keep the indexes.

2) You can use a list of used items. Find any item if it is already int tree before you insert a new node.